# Ruby on Rails : rails_admin force users to use admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a way in [rails_admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin), which forces admin users to use admin instead of using the traditional 'your_model/new' route, make them use 'admin/your_model'?

Comment: I think it's very unclear what you're trying to do. Can you explain it more clearly?

Comment: Ok, say for example I have created a scaffold, with Post model. To create a new post I would go to /posts/new to create my post, rails admin gives us the option to do this through /admin/, if my end user who has the admin role happened to land on /posts/new I would like them to be redirected/forced into the admin panel instead. Just so it is less confusing for the end user not to have two methods of creating posts....

Comment: Ok, I still don't know why would you do that but in application controller you could just check if user is admin and redirect them to the admin panel root url.